# Find the Thévenin equivalent between terminals A and B

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, homework

Can you help me find the Thévenin equivalent between terminals A and B with all the steps?

[image: This is the circuit]

$$R_{eq}=\frac{4}{3}~\Omega\\
V_{eq}=\frac{5}{3}~\mathrm{V}$$

In the first image is the circuit, and below there are the solutions. I need the calculations for the solution of R<sub>eq</sub>.

Here is my attempt:

R<sub>eq</sub> = ((2//3)+3)//1 = 21/26

V<sub>eq</sub> =
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
2+1+3+3&-3
\\\\
-3&3
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
I_1\vphantom{\frac{-1}{R_3}}
\\\\
I_2\vphantom{\frac{-1}{R_3}}
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
2\:\text{V}\vphantom{\frac{-1}{R_3}}
\\\\
3\:\text{V}\vphantom{\frac{-1}{R_3}}
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

This solves to:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
I_1=\frac56\:\text{A}
\\\\
I_2=\frac{11}{6}\:\text{A}
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

So

$$V_{eq}=\frac{5}{6}\times2=\frac{5}{3}V$$

R<sub>eq</sub> = [image]

Comment: Homework questions need to show an attempt at an answer in order to demonstrate where you are getting stuck and prevent the possibility you are using this site during an exam.

Comment: Ok , sorry about that. I've just added my attempt.

Comment: That's just a few out of focus and largely illegible equations that doesn't indicate what you are trying to specifically find. There are two things you are looking for <-- do you understand why I say that? Do you know how to use latex as in formula stuff like this: \$x = \dfrac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\$? = $$$$ `\$x = \dfrac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\$` <-- it would help a lot if you used it.

Comment: Never used sorry. I'll try to edit the post using Latex.

Comment: That might be a big haul. Do you understand the two things you are trying to find? Do you understand that redrawing the circuit can make it look simpler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K5Iu.png I can work Req out in my head.

Comment: The problem is to find the Req and yes I redraw the circuit too to find the Veq but I can't understand how to find out the Req.

Comment: Each and every step in your Req calculation is wrong. Have a look at [this online resistor calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-parallel-and-series-resistor).

Comment: Req= (3+1)//2=4//2= 4/3 Ohms Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**These are just hints to get the OP down the right path**

> *The problem is to find the Req*

Start like this: -

[image]

The resistance (\$R_{AB}\$) is easy now.

Comment: What are the resistence in parallel and in series?
Because I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: I'm trying to calculate it this way:
2 in series with 3 in parallel with 3 all in parallel with 1 but the result is different from the solution.

Comment: What does the short in parallel with the left 3 ohm resistor make that part of the circuit? Redraw it to understand it. Then redraw with the two series resistors combined into one resistor. Then, what are you left with in parallel with the 2 ohm resistor?

Comment: I know that a voltage source in parallel with a resistance eliminates that resistance.
But I still can't figure it out the Req could you draw it for me, maybe I don't know some kind of trick to solve it.

Comment: No, you must draw it yourself. Do you not have access to paper and a pen or pencil? I mean, what does a short across a 3 ohm resistor become? What do two resistors in series become? Redraw it if you want to learn.

Comment: I've just added the Req attempt with the redraw but the result is wrong and I'm not sure if I have simplified the circuit in the right way.
Two resistors in series must be summed

Comment: What resistance is a short circuit? What is 3 ohms in parallel with that short circuit?

Comment: OK, I did it.

The resistor on the short circuit is 0.

Then the 3 ohms resistor is in series with the 1 Ohm resistor, and then what is left is in parallel with the 2 Ohms resistor at the top.

So Req= (3+1)//2=4//2= 4/3 Ohms

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, I accepted the answer.